# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError & java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE in using Twilio SDK

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, twilio-api

I am using Twilio SDK in java to sms from java problem. I tried to use 2 different versions of Twilio library, but I got 2 different errors:

For [twilio-java-sdk-6.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar], I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;Lorg/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver;)V
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.createConnectionOperator(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:99)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:85)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:93)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.<init>(TwilioClient.java:151)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:23)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.<init>(TwilioRestClient.java:19)
at iristk.app.bankAsst.Watson.sendMsg(Watson.java:82)
at iristk.app.bankAsst.Watson.main(Watson.java:100)
```

For [twilio-7.9.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar], I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:46)
at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:97)
at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:122)
at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
at iristk.app.bankAsst.Watson.sendMsg(Watson.java:82)
at iristk.app.bankAsst.Watson.main(Watson.java:91)
```

What is the meaning of the 2 errors? And, if possible, how to solve them?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it seems your application has another version of httpclient&httpcore that is not compatible with wilio-java-sdk. please check your pom.xml and remove dependency of httpclient&httpcore. If you can't see any dependency of httpclient&httpcore in your pom.xml, please run "mvn dependency:tree" to find which dependency contains httpclient&httpcore and then add exclusions nodes to exclude them.

the wilio-java-sdk-6.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar **contains** httpclient(4.2.6) and httpcore(4.2.5)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

twilio-7.9.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar **contains** httpclient(4.5.2) and httpcore(4.4.4)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Mine is neither maven project nor pom.xml exist. If so, how to exclude the conflict httpcore and httpclient. 
I tried to convert mine project into a maven project, but it caused:" Error: Could not find or load main class". 
Can you advice me?

Comment: find httpcore and httpclient from class path

Comment: I don't know what is the kind of you project, so I want to know how does you build the project and start the application firstly

Comment: Do you mean the build path (using eclipse)? I didn't see httpcore and httpclient in the list? Could it be included in other .jar? If so, how to check?

Comment: The [IrisTK](http://iristk.net/download.html) works on Windows, and I am using MAC, so I can't try more to find out how to find the library path. If you was using Eclipse to create/run the application, you can open the build path dialog to check httpcore/httpclient, to open the build path dialog, right click you project in [Project Explorer], click popup menu [Build Path] -> [Configure Build Path ...], and then switch to tab [Library].

Comment: could you list all the library that add into the project, including the wilio-java-sdk-x.x.x-jar-with-dependencies.jar?

Comment: I upload the library as picture [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PKSQq2ayVHTUpCcmtDQkFQeE0). Libraries from /Iristk/.../ are primarily loaded from the iristk framework

Comment: I check the library now. And a common way to resolve NoSuchMethodError/NoSuchFieldError is to run the application again, but add "-verbose:class" to JVM startup command line. I will show all the class was loading from while file/location, then we find out the "bad" jar.

Comment: I can't find which library may contains httpclient/httpcore from the picture. Another way to find:  in Eclipse, click menu [Search] -> [Search ...], the [search dialog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwQ08hvahX_lLXNEcVFubTgwMDQ/view) shows, and switch to tab [Java Search], enter search string "org.apache.http.client.HttpClient"(a class in httpclient jar), and options [Search For] set to "Type", [Limit To] set to "Declarations", [Search In] set to "Sources"+"Required Project"+"Application libraries", and the do search, wish all the HttpClient could be found."

Comment: Yes, It work. I get the search [result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PKSQq2ayVHNFlvcjRBSGlKTGc)

Comment: it should be caused by the httpcore/httpclient classes in commons.jar from IrisTK/core/lib